# Android GridView check item on previous honeycomb versions

Tags: android, gridview, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-2.3-gingerbread, checkedtextview

So i have the following GridView declaration:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/payment_form_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:listSelector="@null"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp" />
```

Each child on the GridView is built on the adapter with the following layout:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/green_radio"
    android:drawablePadding="6dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
    android:textSize="22sp" />
```

The `@drawable/green_radio` is a StateList drawable that i use to show an arrow on the left of the selected item of the GridView.

This code works perfectly on any Android device with at least API level 11 (Honeycomb).
On devices with previous versions the arrow didn't appear when i check the items on the GridView.

After some debugging i notice that the GridView was not setting the pressed child item as checked (something that occurs on API Level 11+) and thus the arrow is not displayed.

Any ideas why this is happening?